# missing Form class when Printing from c#

Tags: c#, printing, fonts

I am trying to understand how to print from C# using "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019". I have an example program but on attempting to compile I get errors:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1069  The type name 'Font' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.    nemonlabel  E:\usr\Nemonlabel\nemonlabel02\nemonlabel\Printroutine.cs   9   Active

and

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1069  The type name 'PrintPageEventArgs' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing.Printing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly. nemonlabel  E:\usr\Nemonlabel\nemonlabel02\nemonlabel\Printroutine.cs   19  Active

It would seem that these should not happen Can anyone suggest what is missing from the example code (below)?

```
/************************************/
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class PrintingExample
{
    private Font printFont;   //First error
    private StreamReader streamToPrint;
    static string filePath;

    public PrintingExample()
    {
        Printing();
    }

    // The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed.
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)  //Second error
    {
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float yPos = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
        String line = null;

        // Calculate the number of lines per page.
        linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
            printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

        // Iterate over the file, printing each line.
        while (count < linesPerPage &&
            ((line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            yPos = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
                leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
            count++;
        }

        // If more lines exist, print another page.
        if (line != null)
            ev.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            ev.HasMorePages = false;
    }

    // Print the file.
    public void Printing()
    {
        try
        {
            streamToPrint = new StreamReader(filePath);
            try
            {
                printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
                // Print the document.
                pd.Print();
            }
            finally
            {
                streamToPrint.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // This is the main entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sampleName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
        if (args.Length != 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: " + sampleName + " <file path>");
            return;
        }
        filePath = args[0];
        new PrintingExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a reference to `System.Drawing.Common` in your project.

Comment: Thanks, I assume that you mean to add "using System.Drawing.Common", I tried that and it generated an error": Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ConsoleApp1 C:\Users\Mark Hubelbank\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs 5 Active
If you mean to put it somewhere else, I need to know exactly where. This is the first c# project I have started.